# Firebase Admin SDK with Java

Tags: java, firebase, sdk, firebase-admin

I am trying to setup firebase admin sdk in a Java project. Following the steps at https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_the_sdk I successfully added the sdk by adding the dependency to my build.gradle using,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.0.0'
}
```

then ran `gradle build` which returned BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

The next step in the guide uses multiple Firebase classes which I do not know where to locate. It tells me to initialize the SDK by using:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

The guide doesn't show where to import these Firebase classes from either. I assume the classes were downloaded after I ran build.gradle but I cant seem to locate any of these classes. Does anyone know what location the gradle should've downloaded it to or what import I must use?

Answer (score 2):

The guide need more precise contents and example.

I have integrated Firebase with my current Spring boot project by following these blog [savicprvoslav/Spring-Boot-starter](https://github.com/savicprvoslav/Spring-Boot-starter)
  , it was out dated too as using new Firebase sdk is strongly recommended. You can check my question and answer here with sample updated code. [Stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156777/can-not-resolve-firebaseoptions-using-latest-firebase-sdk-dependency/47169757#47169757)
The blog suggested to use this code within a configuration file (with **@Configuration** annotation ).

Answer (score 1):

The Java [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java) may be a good place to look.

The `Database.java` file has some of the imports you're looking for:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the JAR file from mvnrepository and include it in your project.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise a bean with this snippet.

How I'm doing it ->

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseAppConfig {

    @SneakyThrows
    public FirebaseAppConfig() {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("filepath");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    }


}
```

This is the bean that provides the auth for your operations. The classes can be imported directly from the mvn/gradle dependency but they NEED to be combined with auth to work.