# Can not resolve FirebaseOptions using latest Firebase SDK dependency

Tags: spring, maven, firebase, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to integrate my spring-boot rest api with Firebase by these following tutorial:
[savicprvoslav](https://github.com/savicprvoslav/Spring-Boot-starter)

I need to **verify the userTokenId** using Firebase SDK which is generated by a front end application.

The above git guide used

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

which is already deprecated and suggesting to use latest Firebase SDK [
[maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-server-sdk/3.0.3)]

According to the Firebase SDK integration guide we should use

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Old practice:**

```
InputStream inputStream = FirebaseConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configPath);

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setServiceAccount(inputStream)
                .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl).build();
```

**New Practice:**

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();
```

I have tried to use  it (**removed the old one**) but it failed to resolve lots of dependencies like
**FirebaseOption** which  can only resolved by old maven dependencies(**firebase-server-sdk 3.0.3**)

I am really very confused ! Can not find any updated example project. A sample project will very helpful (example code  which initialize the firebase sdk ) .

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately Firebase has **updated** their documentation and now suggesting these below maven configuraiton , which resolved the problem perfectly. I think it was a **outdated documentation** issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please follow this link [Firebase SDK Installation guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

In addition , if you are behind **corporate proxy**, you need to set proxy like this:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "your_proxy_host");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "your_proxy_port");
```

so complete code to initialize Firebase instance is:

```
 URL fileUrl = FirebaseConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource(configPath);
FileInputStream fisTargetFile = new FileInputStream(fileUrl.getFile());
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "your_proxy_host");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "your_proxy_port");
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fisTargetFile))
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Hope it will be helpful to others.